# Make a bootable internal drive to install Ubuntu on current drive?

Tags: installation, boot, hard-drive, boot-failure

Is it possible to mount/burn Ubuntu 10.10 on a clean Drive, so that I can boot using that drive with the ISO image and install the OS on my other internal drive, while currently being in *Try Ubuntu* state?

My problems is that the DVD drive is corrupted and does not burn ISO properly; after install the hard drive wont boot. The only way is to use that CD to get my computer running in *Try Ubuntu* state.

Downloaded the new Ubuntu 10.10 ISO and trying to figure out how to make my 2nd internal hard drive become a bootable device so I can choose from to boot in BIOS.

Comment: I think that it would help us if we knew the model of the machine and the OS that you are trying to do this from. There are differences between hard disks, CD-ROMs and USB memory sticks but data is just data as far as the medium is concerned. You may have an issue with the ISO burning program. It may not accept a hard disk as suitable media. Then again it just may accept it, not knowing any better. Then all you have to do is boot from this hard disk first. Doing what you want is not beyond the realms of possibility, in my opinion.

Comment: The issue is I can not burn it to the hard drive that is empty I cannot find a suitable software. Second I have ubuntu installed on my primary hard drive , since I used the CD to make a fresh install and the CD was corrupted , I was not aware of the fact that now My hard Drive is not GOING to boot, being able to Have the COMPUTER running AT ALL is through TRY UBUNTU option on the CD

Answer (score 1):

You can try either making a bootable flash drive or unetbootin.

Unetbootin will run on Windows. When installing the Ubuntu Desktop ISO, choose the free drive  as the location to install into, then boot from your drive.

[Unetbootin home page](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to write your .iso directly to the disk.

`sudo dd if=UbuntuImage.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M`

Replace the X in sdX with your storage device letter. To find out which it is, you can use **lsblk** which will list your storage devices. In my case my drive that I have is "sda".

`NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
sda      8:0    0 37.3G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0    3G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1   8:1    0 34.3G  0 part /`

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest making a bootable USB flash device. Ubuntu.com tells you how.

If you really can't do that, it is possible to boot the ISO image in a Virtual Machine within your current OS, and use that to install it to your existing drive. I'm not sure which VM systems might let you do this, but KVM definitely does. You need to have adjusted your partition table first because moving it underneath a running OS would be *very* bad, and you'd need to do it very carefully, but it would be possible. (Possible on Linux anyway, I don't know about Windows.) Possible, but *not* recommended.

If you're using Windows as your current OS then I would recommend using the "WUBI" installer (also available at Ubuntu.com) and then you don't need a CD either.

Honestly though, get a friend to burn a disk for you ... it'll be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to copy the iso to the clean hard drive and boot it using grub2.
MultiBootUSB uses a script that you can use in Linux, say from the Live CD, and another for use in Windows:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1518273

The following page shows how to do this from scratch:

http://www.panticz.de/MultiBootUSB

PendriveLinux.com shows a similar method but you need to type the code by hand and not copy/paste it:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/